# Rim damage from scraping kerb.. Is it only cosmetic or something more?Should I get it checked?

Tags: wheels, sidewall-damage

Ok, so today coming out of the shopping centre carpark I scrapped my rear left rim on the kerb.
I’m worried because it looks really bad & is around most of the rim. There are a few deep spots of damage..
I wasn’t driving fast probably about 10kms p/hr

Not sure if it’s just really bad cosmetic damage or whether there would be damage to the tire and car?? What should I do & is it ok to drive with it like that ?

Ps. I’m a total noob when it comes to cars so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks enter image description here

[image]

Comment: A better photo would be helpfull

Comment: For whomever put a closed vote on this, it's technically ***not*** about tire health, but about the mechanical viability of the rim. While related, it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image doesn't show much details, but from what I can see there is no structural damage, just scratches.

As long as it's not dented, bent or cracked, you should be fine driving it.

Comment: Sorry I could only add one picture. Thanks for your reply :)